# ValueError: X has 1 features, but MinMaxScaler is expecting 4 features as input

Tags: python, tensorflow

**I receive this error every time then I want to make**

```
scaler.transform(model_inputs)
```

Here is my data

```
 
df = pd.DataFrame({'y': close, 'h':close_high_o,'o':open_arr_o,'l':close_low_o}) #'ds': timestamp, ,'t':timestamp_arr_o

df = df[['y','h','o','l']] 


 
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
scaled_data = scaler.fit_transform(df)
```

All work good until here:

```
total_dataset = df.values
model_inputs = total_dataset[len(total_dataset) - test_data - prediction_days:]
print(model_inputs) 
model_inputs = model_inputs.reshape(-1, 1)  
model_inputs = scaler.transform(model_inputs)
```

In line 162 always receive follow error:

```
ValueError: X has 1 features, but MinMaxScaler is expecting 4 features as input.
```

Comment: Remove the reshape step ? `model_inputs = model_inputs.reshape(-1, 1)`

Comment: Yes, error is gone, but inext in code I need to predict values and make invers_transform, and receve error egain. 
`prediction = scaler.inverse_transform(prediction)` and receive error **prediction = scaler.inverse_transform(prediction)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to change **transform** on **fit_transform**

```
model_inputs = scaler.fit_transform(model_inputs)
```